# How to postback OnSelectedIndexChanged with ASP RadioButtonList after unselecting?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a cancer asp (3.5) radiobuttonlist that PostsBack on SelectedIndexChanged

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSelectQuoteOrSolution" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblSelectQuoteOrSolution_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Vertical">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Quote ID" Value="QuoteID"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Solution ID" Value="SolutionID"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

At a certain point I unselect any selections on the radiobuttonlist using jQuery

```
$("#<%= rblSelectQuoteOrSolution.ClientID %> input[type=radio]").prop('checked',false);
```

This is a problem because if the user comes back to the radiobuttonlist after making whatever changes they wanted and they click on the same radiobutton that was selected before, the OnSelectedIndexChanged event will not fire because it seems only the client is aware that the RadioButton selection has been cleared, the server side control thinks its still selected!

Any ideas about how to get the radiobuttonlist to post back to the server even if the user selects the radiobutton that was previously selected? This might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

```html
First Fall You have remove AutoPostback=true; In Javascript: $("#rblSelectQuoteOrSolution:checked").on('change',function(){ //Code. })
                       Or
$("input:radio:checked").on('change',function(){ //Code. })
```

Comment: But I want the radiobutton list to autopostback. The issue is when I unselect the options on the radiobuttonlist with jQuery, I can't figure out how to set the control to postback if the user re-selects the option that I previously unselected with JQuery.

Comment: For example, if I set AutoPostback to false and I set the javascript like in your example to postback on change of that control my SelectedIndexChanged event that is on the radiobuttonlist will never fire.